# Delete rows containing a certain time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I'm sorting appointment records in Excel and want to remove rows containing appointment times before 9am (currently stored in column B), but leave the blank cells in place for now. I've tried running the following code, but it's giving me a syntax error. What have I missed?

```
Sub ApptTime()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "B")) And _
    (Cells(i, "B").Value < TimeSerial(9, 0, 0)  And _
    (Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""     Then
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing `Next i` before `End Sub`

Comment: *it's giving me a syntax error*, but you didn't include that error message in your post. It's on the screen right in front of you. Why isn't it here where we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `Next i` before `End Sub` and you have some rogue brackets that need removing.

```
Sub ApptTime()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "B")) And _
         Cells(i, "B").Value2 < TimeSerial(9, 0, 0)  And _
         Cells(i, "B").Value2 <> ""     Then
           Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach, to loop through *numeric* cells only and skipping blanks:

```
Sub ApptTime()
    Dim iArea As Long, iCell As Long

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) ' reference column B cells from row 1 down to last not empty one with "numeric" content only
        For iArea = .Areas.count To 1 Step -1 ' loop through referenced range "Areas" from the last one backwards
            For iCell = .Areas(iArea).count To 1 Step -1 'loop through current area cells form the last one backwards
                With .Areas(iArea).Cells(iCell, 1) 'reference current cell in current area
                    If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value < TimeSerial(9, 0, 0) And .Value <> "" Then .EntireRow.Delete
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```